How to compute $\displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^n \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt k & -1\\ 1 & \sqrt k \end{pmatrix}$?
I was wondering if the following product of matrices had any closed form in terms of $n$:
$$\prod_{k=0}^n
\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt k & -1\\
1 & \sqrt k
\end{pmatrix}$$
The motivation of finding its closed form is to further simplify/reduce the solution I presented here.

The product must have determinant $(n+1)!$, as the determinant of $\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{k}&-1\1&\sqrt{k} \end{pmatrix}$ is $k+1$.

Equivalent: $$\prod_{k=0}^n\big(\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{-1}\big)$$

There is little chance it possesses a closed form, given that it comes from a problem related to Pythagoras's snail, which itself cannot be solved in a closed form.

Diagonal these matrices $\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt k & -1\\1 & \sqrt k\end{pmatrix}$, we have:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt k & -1\\
1 & \sqrt k
\end{pmatrix} = P^{-1}\cdot \pmatrix{\sqrt{k}+ \mathbf{i}&0\\0&\sqrt{k}- \mathbf{i} }\cdot P$$
where
$$P= \pmatrix{-\mathbf{i}&1\\\mathbf{i}&1 }$$
then
$$\begin{align}
L&:= \prod_{k=0}^n
\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt k & -1\\
1 & \sqrt k
\end{pmatrix}\\
&= P^{-1} \cdot \left(\prod_{k=0}^n\pmatrix{\sqrt{k}+ \mathbf{i}&0\\0&\sqrt{k}- \mathbf{i} }    \right)\cdot P \\
&=P^{-1}\cdot \pmatrix{\prod_{k=0}^n\left(\sqrt{k}+ \mathbf{i}\right)&0\\0&\prod_{k=0}^n\left(\sqrt{k}+ \mathbf{i}\right) }    \cdot P\\
L&= \color{red}{\pmatrix{\frac{1}{2}\left(\prod_{k=0}^n\left(\sqrt{k}+ \mathbf{i}\right) + \prod_{k=0}^n\left(\sqrt{k}- \mathbf{i}\right) \right) &\frac{\mathbf{i}}{2}\left(\prod_{k=0}^n\left(\sqrt{k}+ \mathbf{i}\right) - \prod_{k=0}^n\left(\sqrt{k}- \mathbf{i}\right) \right)\\
\frac{\mathbf{i}}{2}\left(\prod_{k=0}^n\left(\sqrt{k}+ \mathbf{i}\right) - \prod_{k=0}^n\left(\sqrt{k}- \mathbf{i}\right) \right)&\frac{1}{2}\left(\prod_{k=0}^n\left(\sqrt{k}+ \mathbf{i}\right) + \prod_{k=0}^n\left(\sqrt{k}- \mathbf{i}\right) \right)}}
\end{align}
$$

This doesn't look helpful to me (but I won't downvote). We already have an isomorphism $$\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\b&a\end{bmatrix}\cong a+bi=a+b\sqrt{-1}$$ so the expression in the OP is trivially equivalent to $$\prod_{k=0}^n\big(\sqrt{k}+i\big)$$

@mr_e_man these are really two versions of the same argument, since once you rewrite your product in terms of matrices using your isomorphism you will get NN2 s matrices.(Indeed the upper left and lower right entries are the real part of your number and the other two are the imaginary/negative-maginary part).

@mr_e_man I don't get what you meant. The product of matrices are in $\mathbb{C}^{\color{red}{2\times 2}}$ while your product is in $\mathbb{C}$, do you agree with me about that?

The matrices in the OP are in $\mathbb R^{2\times2}$, and have the form given in my first comment. Such matrices are isomorphic to complex numbers. If we could evaluate $$\prod_{k=0}^n\big(\sqrt{k}+i\big)=x+iy\in\mathbb C$$ then we would also get $$\prod_{k=0}^n\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt k&-1\1&\sqrt k\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x&-y\y&x\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb R^{2\times2}$$ by the isomorphism.

@mr_e_man So, there is a problem because the product of matrices must be in $\mathbb{C}^{\color{red}{2\times 2}}$.

There are no imaginary numbers in the OP's matrices.

@mr_e_man Anyway, $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2} \subset \mathbb{C}^{2 \times 2} $. The main problem is that the product must be in $\mathbb{C}^{2 \times 2} $ and cannot be in $\mathbb{C} $

@NN2, what he is saying is that there is an embedding (ring homomorphism) of $\mathbb{C}$ into $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ and that the matrices in this product are all in the image of this embedding, so you can just compute the product in $\mathbb{C}$ and then embed. As I explained in an earlier comment, this is completely equivalent to your approach. Both of you would do well to consider the other's approach more carefully!

@mr_e_man, nice, maybe rewrite in the exponential (amplitude phase) form?

@user619894 - That would lead us in a circle, back to the linked question.

A solution using $2\times2$ rotation matrices:
Note that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{k} & - 1 \\
1 & \sqrt{k}
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\sqrt{k + 1}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\phi_k) & -\sin(\phi_k) \\
\sin(\phi_k) & \cos(\phi_k)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\phi_k = \text{atan}(1/\sqrt{k})$.  Since multiplying $2\times 2$ rotations corresponds to simply adding the angles, we can write
$$
\prod_{k=0}^n
\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{k} & - 1 \\
1 & \sqrt{k}
\end{bmatrix}
= \left(\prod_{k=0}^n\sqrt{k+1}\right)
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\phi) & -\sin(\phi) \\
\sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with $\phi = \sum_{k=0}^n \phi_k = \sum_{k=0}^n \text{atan}(1/\sqrt{k})$.

This is a step straight backwards. See the link in the OP.
